# Best way to make user see my intended error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have been struggling with handling the  following error messages, for example I want to be able to show the the user a message when the user is trying to re-register with an email address that is already in use, nothing seem to happen when the user click on the signup button , but when I tried to inspect on chrome console, I can see the error message that should display on my console but the user can see the message . please How do I resolve this?

I have tried using all the method i know, including using chrome console

example 1

```
 static async addUser(userInfo) {

    try {
      await users.insertOne({ 
         "name": userInfo.name,
         "email": userInfo.email,
         "password": userInfo.password,
        },
        { w: "majority" },
      )
      return { success: true }
    } catch (e) {
      if (String(e).startsWith("MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error")) {
        return { error: "A user with the given email already exists." }
      }
      console.error(`Error occurred while adding new user, ${e}.`)
      return { error: e }
    }
  }
```

When I use the console to inspect I see the right error message I want to display however the user can't see it

```
email: "A user with the given email already exists."
```

another example of the error message I want the user to see

```
static async register(req, res) {
    try {
      const userFromBody = req.body
      let errors = {}
      if (userFromBody && userFromBody.password.length < 8) {
        errors.password = "Your password must be at least 8 characters."
      }
      if (userFromBody && userFromBody.name.length < 3) {
        errors.name = "You must specify a name of at least 3 characters."
      }

      if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
        res.status(400).json(errors)
        return
      }
```

I expect the user to see the error message from the interface not through the console

Comment: use connect-flash library for handling error messages and displaying. see the docs if need help ask.